# Would it be possible that a broken glass can return to its original state spontaneous at 0K?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

my teacher said that a broken glass can't fix itself spontaneous because of the second law of thermodynamics, entropy won't decrease in a isolated system. But when the temperature is at 0k, then entropy becomes zero. So if the broken glass can return to its original state, then this doesn't violate any laws, right? Does it means this is possible?

Comment: Your teacher is referring to entropy of *kinetic* energy at 0 K.  If you pick up a tea cup at 0 K and smash it to the ground, it will most definitely break.

Comment: Is it possible? No, it isn't. The glass is not a closed system, not even at low temperatures. 0K is not a physical temperature, to begin with.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I can put the glass in a box, which is a closed system.

Comment: @Neil: what's the meaning of entropy of kinetic energy? Do you mean that the total entropy is not zero at 0k?

Comment: @alst Kinetic energy refers to movement of an object in general, but more specifically in this case I'm referring to the internal jittering of the atoms that is directly associated with temperature.  At 0 K, the atoms don't jitter.  This creates some strange properties at that temperature, but you'd certainly never see entropy *reversed* on that object.

Comment: @Neil: But  entropy is zero at 0k, then whatever the glass becomes, entropy  equals to 0, it won't decrease.

Comment: @Neil And isn't that atom will vibrate at a high frequency to follow the uncertainty principle?

Comment: @alst A broken glass won't reassemble without requiring more energy to be added, regardless of temperature.  The heisenberg uncertainty principle just means you can't hope to measure the position and momentum at the same moment in time.  Not sure I understand your point.

Comment: @alst: The box is not a closed system, either, unless it's perfectly reflective and that is forbidden by the third law of thermodynamics.

Comment: @Neil : My problem... my English is not good...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero Kelvin is not attainable by a physical system.

> [Why is absolute zero (0 kelvin or −273.15°C) an impossible goal?](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn18541-what-happens-at-absolute-zero/)
>
> Practically, the work needed to remove heat from a gas increases the colder you get, and an infinite amount of work would be needed to cool something to absolute zero. In quantum terms, you can blame Heisenberg’s uncertainty principle, which says the more precisely we know a particle’s speed, the less we know about its position, and vice versa. If you know your atoms are inside your experiment, there must be some uncertainty in their momentum keeping them above absolute zero – unless your experiment is the size of the whole universe.

Let us not quibble about this, let us suppose a crystal very close to absolute zero in a thermally isolated box with. It has its lowest possible entropy.

To break the lattice energy must be supplied. Suppose an equally cold stone detaches itself from the roof (gravity supplying the energy) and falls on the crystal. The system is now broken crystal, fallen stone and the kinetic energy has increased or statistically the number of microstates is orders of magnitude than it was at t=0, i.e. the entropy has been increased.

There is no way the crystal pieces can be connected again without energy being supplied, which will introduce more microstates. To get back to the original entropy of the crystal energy has to be supplied outside the system, to cool it.

So the broken pieces can be back together again in an open system, where one has to count the total and entropy will be increasing.